# How do combine 2 xPath queries

Tags: xpath

I am trying to get a list of all element nodes that have a child of `<min value="1" />` and do not have a child of `<mustSupport value="true" />`.

Both of these 2 queries work separately,

```xml
//differential/element[child::min[@value='1'] ]

//differential/element[not (child::mustsupport)]
```

but produce no results when combined.

```xml
//differential/element[child::min[@value='1']  and not [child::mustsupport] ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's a typo, but you have `[ ]` instead of `( )` on your `not`.

Also, xpath is case sensitive.

Lastly, the `child::` axis is not necessary (although it's fine if it makes it easier to understand).

Try this...

```xml
//differential/element[min[@value='1'] and not(mustSupport[@value='true'])]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help.  I didn't think it was a typo, but apparently it was.